# chartjs - react data does not reach end of x -axis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, chart.js

I am using chart js to display the total covid vaccinations of each day for a given date range in greece . The problem is that while my totals are correct the line chart does not finish on the last date but way sooner . I think this is a css problem as I have tested my data and it is correct

Starts from dec 28 and should finish on may 3 . The result on ap 18 is the result of may 3

[image]

My code :

```
   //function that returns the range of dates on the x-axis 
    const getDaysRangeArray = (start,end) =>{
      
      let dateArr = [];
    
      for(let dt=new Date(start); dt<=end; dt.setDate(dt.getDate()+1)){
      dateArr.push(new Date(dt));
      }
    
      return dateArr;
    }




    const Chart = (props) => {
 
  let daylist = getDaysRangeArray(new Date((props.from).toLocaleDateString('en-US')), new Date((props.to).toLocaleDateString('en-US')));

  function getTotalVaccinations(data){   
    let sum= data.reduce((acc,itm)=>{
      if(itm.totalvaccinations!=="undefined"){
        return acc + itm.totalvaccinations;
      }
    },0);
    
    return sum;
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex items-center place-items-center  w-full mx-auto">
      {(props.covidData).length>0 
         && 
        <Line
        type = "line"
        data={{
          //the date range 
          labels:[...daylist.map(d=>d.toDateString().slice(4,10))],
        datasets: [
            {
              label: 'total vaccinations',
              //the total vaccinations array for each date of given range 
              data:[...props.covidData.map((d:any)=>getTotalVaccinations(d)).sort((a:any,b:any)=>{
                  return a-b 
              })],
              backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
              
              ],
              borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
             
              ],
              borderWidth: 1,
              pointRadius: 0,
            },
          ],
        }}
        height={400}
        width={600}
        options={{
          maintainAspectRatio: false,
          scales: {
            yAxes: [
              {
                ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                },
              },
            ],
            xAxes: [{
              type: 'time',
              time: {
                displayFormats: {
                  'millisecond': 'MMM DD',
                  'second': 'MMM DD',
                  'minute': 'MMM DD',
                  'hour': 'MMM DD',
                  'day': 'MMM DD',
                  'week': 'MMM DD',
                  'month': 'MMM DD',
                  'quarter': 'MMM DD',
                  'year': 'MMM DD',
                }
              }
            }],
          },
          legend: {
            labels: {
              fontSize: 35,
            },
          },
        }}
      />
    
    }

   </div>    

  )
}

export default Chart;
```

If I reduce the date range the data is displayed correctly and makes it to last date (mar 2 - mar 5 )

[image]

I would appreciate your help .

Comment: Chart.js matches data to the labels so are you sure your data array is the same length as your labels array because it looks like your labels array contains more items as your data array

Comment: @LeeLenalee I will inspect this more but I am 90% sure .  If you see the second image the length is correct

Comment: Yeah so there you have the same length of data array as labels array looks like

Comment: Just to get other factors out of the way ... did you place your data in a simple chart.js example to see it working properly?

Comment: @gaitat my data is fetched from an external api

Comment: yes but I am sure you can capture the data you used to create the first image (for example)